# How to config number of connections on nginx?

Tags: nginx

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr   zone=perip:10m;    

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name   wx110.cn;
    root /data/www/wx120;

    limit_conn  perip 10;

    location / {
        index  index.html ;
    }
}
```

---

ab -n 100 -c 100 http://wx110.cn/test.html

---

result:Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine with your config. I guess there is issue with testing process. Try to execute this code: `for i in {0..2000}; do (curl -Is http://wx110.cn/ | head -n1 &) 2>/dev/null; done`.

And I recommend you enable access logs in your config file: `access_log /var/log/nginx/wx110.cn.log;`. Then you will be able monitor log file while testing: `tail -f /var/log/nginx/wx110.cn.log`

Comment: using ab test , logs show 100 lines : 169.254.142.1 - - [30/Sep/2019:09:21:10 +0800] "GET /test.html HTTP/1.0" 20        0 4 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3"

Comment: @frontGirl try to enable error log ```error_log /var/log/nginx/wx110.cn_error.log;``` and repeat curl test.

Comment: after curl test , access_log has many lines : 169.254.142.4 - - [02/Oct/2019:20:51:29 +0800] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (i386-redhat        -linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"